# Free PHP Login Library

Tags: php, mysql, authentication

I'm designing a new website and I need a login system (Preferably in PHP and mySQL). I've written ad-hoc login systems before and I'm aware of all the security involved, etc. But as Jeff Atwood said, [Never design what you can steal](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2004/12/never-design-what-you-can-steal.html). So I'm wondering if there are any good PHP login/sign-in libraries. Can you recommend any?

### some specifics

- I am trying to avoid php frameworks if at all possible (there is no reason to import one just for the login function)
- Also, I am aware I could simply use a social login or open-id, unless you are aware of a REALLY good library for this I would also prefer to not have to have to use something (open-id) I've never dealt with before
- Finally I need to be able to edit the user information in the mySQL database

Comment: Bummer to #1, because TankAuth for CodeIgniter is an outstanding auth library.

Comment: http://pear.php.net/Auth

Comment: This question is more on-topic at [Software Recommendations](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**UserCake**

http://usercake.com/

- Login Register Lost password recovery
- Update password Update user email
- Email templates (optional) SHA1
- security + Salt / Hash Account
- activation (optional) Resend
- activation email (optional) User
- groups (Basic, id - group_name)
- Multilingual support

**Or**

You can try
http://phpuserclass.com/

Answer (score 4):

**Some points before the answer.**

1. You may rethink your strategy on frameworks. Modern frameworks like Zend Framework and also Symfony2 are loosely coupled. This means: you dont need to download/use the whole framework.
2. Another reason to rethink it, is that these frameworks are often robust, widely tested and used. In terms of performance they are not always of huge impact, especially with apc and other optimization methods, so are you affraid you will use too much harddisk space?
3. Your question is about something specific but easily done. This is exactly the type of stuff that frameworks are good at. Codeigniter, Zend Framework, Symfony, Symfony2 (am I missing one?), all offer code that will allow you to do this in maximum a matter of hours.

**Libraries I would consider**

1. Zend_Auth (has only zend_exception as hard depencencies). It's lightweight and has many options for integration with openauth and such. (requires about 10 php files) http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.auth.html
2. Apache ZetaComponents (before ezcomponents)
   http://incubator.apache.org/zetacomponents/documentation/trunk/Authentication/tutorial.html
3. Pear LiveUser
   http://pear.php.net/package/LiveUser/download/
4. If you were to consider codeigniter, check this out: http://codeigniter.com/wiki/Category:Libraries::Authentication/

Comment: @Arend - even if not using MVC or any other framework for that matter would that affect the use of using something such as Zend_Auth, or would you recommend using another framework for integrating into a bespoke PHP website?

Comment: Yeah, sure, all of these examples are quite lightweight - most of them have a dependency structure (some components depend on the other). But you almost never have to use the whole framework. In many cases they also offer a mvc structure, but you don't have to use it. CodeIgniter, I'm not sure, I've not used it. I myself use symfony a lot.

Comment: @Arend - sounds good thank you. Would you recommend Symfony for something similar to what the OP mentioned?

Comment: @lethalMango: it depends. Are you considering doing this more then once? Each framework has a steep learning curve. It took me about a year to really understand everything in symfony, but it was worth it, because I can reuse a lot of things. What the OP wants is more or less part of my symfony 'boilerplate' project, and it's for example with sf 1.4 easy to realize by installing doctrineguard or an openid plugin.

Comment: @Arend - As it stands I have several projects that I'd like to get finished, but they are all written bespoke without using any frameworks. As you say with the steep learning curve it requires a lot of dedication to learn it all which is great, but with limited time I would assume proves quite difficult. I'm actually looking at implementing a solution the same as the OP, but weighing up the options of using something such as UserCake vs (what looks to be more versatile) SF or Zend_Auth. With the site mainly built and now adding the login, do you have any recommendations?

Comment: @lethalMango You can try to play with the symfony sanbox and see if it fits. For me it was also an introduction in OOP PHP and MVC pattern. If you are already familiar with such concepts, the curve should be much less steep. I can imagine if the projects are quite similar a framework might offer you a nice way to structure and maintain your projects. Otherwise, I would investigate in to Zend_Auth or roll your own authentication system.

Comment: @Arend - thanks for all the advice.. given me plenty of stuff to be working on! :)

Answer (score 1):

[This tutorial](http://evolt.org/PHP-Login-System-with-Admin-Features?from=1250&comments_per_page=50) is a bit on the old side, but it is one of the best out there and is very well done.  There's no framework, it's just plain old good OOP PHP.][1](http://evolt.org/PHP-Login-System-with-Admin-Features?from=1250&comments_per_page=50)  The code is available for download on the Tut.

It's well written, includes Cookies, and has a robust back end for user admin.

Answer (score 1):

If the libraries you find do not apply, many of the concepts I presume you'll look into involve either combining [PHP and LDAP](http://php.net/manual/en/book.ldap.php), and/or [PHP and the Apache authentication modules](http://php.net/manual/en/features.http-auth.php).

Your authentication requirements should also respect the principles of [defense in depth](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Defense_in_depth_%28computing%29).

Also, you might need to discover if your project requires authentication for JSON, XML-RPC, or REST APIs that could be operated by non-browser clients.