# PHP Security of login application

Tags: php, security

Hey all of you PHP geeks, and hackers, if some of you listen ;o) 
I'm creating a login system, for some upcoming site, which a lot of people will be using, I'm sure - or at least I hope so :)

- So, my question is: WHEN is my login system and stuff like that secure enough? Is it ever gonna be "secure enough"?

I got form validation, where I check, what's send to the database. My passwords are md5 hashed. And people are told to create strong passwords.

- Are there something called: "Secure enough"?

  - I'm thinking: All the big sites like facebook and stuff like that, must be having more then this? Is it something that I need? And if so, how?

Some links and stuff like that, would be nice. Thanks in forward :o)

Comment: [Public key encryption for web site authentication and identification](http://www.phoenix-web.us/compinfo/pubkey/index.html)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Security is a never-ending process. Your code will never be "secure enough." You should apply all of the security techniques you know, and learn those you don't. Then stay current, monitor your logs, and update your code as necessary.

In general, a login system is a bad place to reinvent the wheel. There are plenty of commonly-used systems available that have been checked and rechecked by many eyes, and are probably more secure than any you or I will be able to write ourselves. This is a good opportunity to take advantage of the "wisdom of the masses" and use a well-tested third-party system.

Comment: @George Cummins What do you mean with: Stay current, monitor your logs? I'm glad you replied this fast. Btw, I'm a dane, so some english is a bit hard to me.

Comment: @Kolind: Your English is great. I would have never guessed it was a second language for you. By "stay current," I mean continue reading and learning. The trade magazines and online forums will be a good source of reading to learn about new exploits and how to stop them. "Monitor your logs" means examine the log files produced by your web server and applications. Look for patterns that indicate malicious activity, such as repetitive requests from a particular IP, or requests to non-existant or hidden URLs.

Comment: @George Cummins That was very kind of you, I'm glad you think my English isn't that bad ;) When that's said: Those log files. Are those, some I have to setup my self, or the server automatically do this? And how do I store the log files. etc etc. Do you have a link or something to configuring my log files?

Comment: @Kolind: The location of your server log files varies based on the type of web server you use. If you use Apache on a UNIX or Linux box, check /var/log/http or /var/log/apache. You can also check the output of phpinfo() for the location of your PHP log file (look for the `error_log` directive). If someone else maintains your web server, they will be able to locate these logs for you. Finally, you can include logging in your application. You can, for example, write to text file each time a user logs in and include the date, time, and username. Similar entries can be created for database edits.

Comment: @George Cummins I see. I'll be looking at this. Thanks for your replies. Those just made the evening full of reading and coding. I love that ;)

Comment: @Kolind: I'm happy I could help in a small way. I wish you luck with your studies, and I hope you find the solution that best fits your needs. Enjoy!

Answer (score 4):

If you're worried about security, you shouldn't use md5 hashes to store your passwords. Md5 is designed to be fast, meaning that if a hacker gets your hashes, they can be cracked quickly. You should use something like bcrypt for storing passwords.

http://codahale.com/how-to-safely-store-a-password/

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I will look at this. I part of my question is: When is my applications (login system etc.) ready to publish on the internet?

Comment: @Kolind A system is secure enough when it takes more work to break into than there is value inside. For example, my SO account doesn't need to be as secure as my bank, which is why my bank uses two factor authentication. Using that definition, you'll have to decide how secure your site needs to be. However, as others have said, writing this yourself opens you up to a number of unnecessary risks.

Answer (score 2):

You have all kinds of security vulnerabilities:

- SQL injection
- Cross-site scripting (XSS)
- Cross-site request forgery (CSRF)
- Session attacks
- Using nonsecured connection (non-HTTPS)
- Passwords in plaintext/weak encrypting
- Weak passwords

I recommend you to look them all up and choose a framework for developing web applications that already resolves all or most of these issues for you automatically.

BTW: md5 is not safe anymore, I recommend you to use `hash_hmac('sha256', $password, $salt)` which also takes care of salting.

Comment: @Mirtes I'm already trying to avoid SQL Injection and XSS. But the other ones I'll be looking at. Btw - frameworks seem so complicated. I'm trying to learn PHP "fully" before I'll grab a framework like CodeIgniter.

Answer (score 2):

It's kinda ironic how I found this after reading over [my own question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6346922/free-php-login-library).

Having written a couple of login libraries myself, heres the advice I can give:

1. **Validate form input** (server side), to prevent XSS (cross site scripting), CSS injection, & SQL injecttion

   - for correct length
   - [ctype](http://php.net/manual/en/book.ctype.php)
   - If ctype is not alpha numeric [add slashes](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.addslashes.php)
   - Add [html entities](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php) to prevent XSS, if HTML is imperitive use an [HTML filter](http://htmlpurifier.org/)
   - Use a [password strength API](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/ajax/GooglePasswordStrength.aspx) to ensure decent passwords
2. [**Hash**](http://phpsec.org/articles/2005/password-hashing.html) the passwords, and don't forget the [salt](http://tomasreimers.com/archives/49)! Also MD5 is weak, use [SHA-256](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.hash.php)
3. **Log the IPs** incase anything goes wrong
4. Make **backups** of your SQL databases

*With all that said I still suggest you use openID or a [php library/class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6346922/free-php-login-library).*

Comment: @Tomas Hello Tomas. Thanks for your reply. I will do so. I like your advice. I'm looking at bcrypt right now. And it seems a bit like, there's not a lot of description of, what bcrypt is. Just a lot about: USE BCRYPT USE BCRYPT! ;o)

Comment: @Kolind, I haven't rn into BCRYPT yet, can you post a link? (I'm actually trying to find the best php login class and materials right now :))

Comment: @Kolind, oh- ummmm- yeah- I don't see a way of getting out of this without looking stupid....

Comment: @Tomas I'm talking about the bcrypt link: http://codahale.com/how-to-safely-store-a-password/

Comment: ik, i was just kinda dumb not to see it before

Answer (score 0):

On my latest little website, I hope I somewhat avoid some level of complexity with security by using openid, instead of fully implementing my own auth system. Thus, I don't really store passwords.

I believe MD5 in considered weak, but I'm not convinced that really matters - if you can keep your hashes safe - by using openid, I took that component out of the equation for me. Granted, if openid gets owned, then, yeah, obviously that's a problem too.

Still, you want to do a fair bit of input filtering. Do what you can to limit the input you do take in, make sure you're running on a fully patched server (check in often) and be sure you're running processes that can't access things they don't strictly need access to. So, for example, if your web service runs as root, well, then you deserve to have your server turned in to a palace of pr0n.

Just some thoughts - granted, I'm not exactly a security guy.